# PHP write a number out of an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, integer

I have a PHP problem.
I need to write a number from a sets of digits 0-9. Each set has 10 digits, each digit once.
I need to count the number of sets that I have to use to write the number.
For example number 10 is written from one set, but number 300 uses 2 sets because it has two zeros.
But, the problem is that 6 and 9 are considered the same. They can be rotated by 180 degrees.
Number 266 will be using one set, 369 also is using one set, but 5666 is using 2 sets.
I would be very grateful if you could somehow help me.
Here is how I have started and stuck up, have no more clue how to loop through it. Tried many things, nothing successful.

```
<?php
function countSet($num) {
 $array = str_split($num); 
 $statarr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
 $a1 = $array; $a2 = $statarr; 
 $result = array_intersect($a1,$a2);
 $count = array_count_values($result); }
?>
```

Comment: Unclear where the "can be rotated" criteria comes from? If you're looking at a classic digital display, 2 and 5 can also be rotated. :)

Comment: Yes @MarkusAO you are right, but in the task is required only for 6 and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to know how many sets you need for a number, you can solve by counting the numbers. For the case of the 9, just replace every 9 by a 6 and divide the number of 6 by two. Something like this (sorry if there's any syntax error, I'm on mobile):

```
function countSet($input) {
    // Convert the input into a string and replace every 9 by a 6. Then convert it to array
    $numbers = str_split(str_replace("9", "6", strval($input)));

    // Count occurrences for each number
    $usedNumbers = array_count_values($numbers);
    
// If we have a 6, must divide it by 2 (6 represents 6 and 9
    if (array_key_exists("6", $usedNumbers)) {
      $usedNumbers["6"] = ceil($usedNumbers["6"] / 2);
    }
    
    // Now we just need to know the max number of occurrences for a single number as our result.
    return max($usedNumbers);
}
```

See an online demo [here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=ZZI_a8MwEMV3g7_DNWSQISSQgMG0pUPp0CVLu5ViFPlcK7Eloz9OTMl378mOQ0M8CKOT3v3eOz29tFUbR6sVvCmHBnrtDQhdIFRocAGo9rp_iKPSK-GkVlTzyn2gY3OpWu8S-I0joI8UXrXq0DhwFcJQpNVp4GCdkeoHuCrAYFtzgYB0socMdj3V0yV8Vhi0RwFJGnTPGN6P4nPlmx0aC89BK7dtLR0Lfxc5NstmC5iltNBux-uJLkke4-gfILGDFsIbg0qghVIbQC4qGBtcunmLxfbaceDIB985SXu0bOIJ6uHGEOB7CUeKjXcYLC2g8dZBITtJYZIjcroGloYEDFpUzkI6RJKNGrIENrY6YJ_jSVpn2WDpP09yDfyW84tOfhOsQEnm7worWE-s5wn5EspWHwP3PtAqxCJEf1C0GcbY8NMlGtDlXXI0WZprjdMRbiE8H7Lna7ccOxh03qggdIMVaM5hNB03eeGbll0fVpplm82GJvcH&v=8.1.3)